# Get the list of all possible email addresses starting from Display Name

Tags: vba, outlook

How could I get, with VBA Excel, the Outlook properties of a single contact for whom I have the User Principal Name?

I am interested in the tab labelled "E-mail Addresses".

I managed to get the PrimarySMTP property, but I would like to get the list of all addresses listed there. The 'alias' property gives me one entry, while there are several others.

This is what I did to get the distribution list memberships:

```
Dim objExchUsr As ExchangeUser 
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim myNameSpace As Namespace 
Dim MyAddrList As AddressList 
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
Dim oDistListEntries As Outlook.AddressEntries
Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry

Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyAddrList = myNameSpace.addressLists("Global Address List")
Set myRecipient = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient(strDisplayname)
myRecipient.Resolve
If myRecipient.Resolved Then
    Set objExchUsr = myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
    Set oDistListEntries = objExchUsr.GetMemberOfList
    For Each oAE In oDistListEntries
        If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry Then
            <Do something with the distribution lists: not relevant  to this problem>
        End If
    Next
End If
```

With this code I get the information shown in the tab 'Member Of' of the Outlook Properties.
How do I get the information that is shown in the tab 'E-mail Addresses'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you could use:

```
Const PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES  As String = _
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F"

Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

addresses = _
NS.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES)
```

Comment: I get an error message when I execute the 'addresses = ...'  instruction:
Error number is -2147467259 
Error description is 'The operation failed.'

Comment: I tried to execute the instruction in the debugger Immediate window, with the 'current user' and I get a 'Type mismatch' error, but it is not the current user that I'm interested in: I have a list of users in an Excel table and I would like to get the addresses for all of them.

Comment: I found that the error message -2147467259 occurs only when I run the code on my own email. The code works for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F"`) using `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. You will get back an array of proxy addresses prefixed with the address type (e.g. "EX:" or "SMTP:")

Comment: I get an error message when trying to retrieve the array of addresses.
Error number is -2147467259 
Error description is 'The operation failed.'

Comment: I found that the error message -2147467259 occurs only when I run the code on my own email. The code works for the other cases.